# Forcing Oozie job to run on specific node

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have a 6 node cluster.

When trying to run an oozie job, it triggers the job in any of the 6 nodes

Is there a way to specify the node in which the oozie shell action should be triggered

Comment: Oozie uses MapReduce framework for launching the launcher job (Mapper) which does the work eventually. So MapReduce jobs are launched randomly on cluster, so it can not be done.

Comment: Thanks. So the only option here is to use cron

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: My requirement is to schedule a spark job every day in a specific node. Is there any options other than crontab?