# oozie shell action execution on particular datanode (or) namenode

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Can we execute oozie shell action from particular nodes. My shell action is being executed on random datanode. Can we configure this somewhere?

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691830/forcing-oozie-job-to-run-on-specific-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Oooze ssh action , and in the ssh action run your bashScript.

Oozie shell action will run on a random dataNode.